# JS calculate current center of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I searched a lot but couldn't find the answer I want. I have a JS script which shows an image when a fixed element is hovered. However I would like to always have the image at the center of the screen, not matter where the user scrolls. How can I reach that?

My JS function:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.trigger').mouseover(function() {
       // find our span
       var elem = $(this).siblings('span');

        // get our img url
       var src = elem.attr('data-original');


        // change span to img using the value from data-original
       elem.replaceWith('<img src="' + src + '"width="400" style="display:block;position:absolute;top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;margin: auto;"/>');

      });

      $('.trigger').mouseout(function() {
       // find our span
       var elem = $(this).siblings('img');

        // get our img url
       var src = elem.attr('src');

        // change img to span using the value from data-original
       elem.replaceWith('<span data-original="'+src+'"></span>');
      });
    });
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rbmd6a39/

I can get offset from the top of page using

> window.pageYOffset;

But I don't know where to put that value to have it in the center.

Comment: Screen or the browser? Like I do not have a100% width and height browser so center of the screen is not the center of the browser.

Comment: Did you tried using css style **margin-top:50%; margin-left:50%;**?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Well sorry, it's just for a demonstration.. Is that really why all the downvotes?

Comment: @popcorn I'm not sure why all the downvote-rage. But it's not hard to find many answers on google, about how to center hor/ver an element. Gave you an upvote if it feels any better - your question is well formatted and you're clearly still learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give that image styles that would make it fixed in the center of your screen. No need for JS there.

Now also works on very large images with `max-width`, `max-height` and `object-fit: contain`!

```
.always-centered {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: contain;
  object-fit: contain;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to use JavaScript for centering it. You could use `position: fixed` and center using `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);`in CSS, which would be less demanding of the client computer.

Using JS, though, it'd be pretty much the same thing: the image would need to be fixedly positioned and you'd define `left` as half of the viewport minus half of your image width.

I suggest using CSS and classes if possible, since this is less convoluted and all calculations will be dealt be the browser itself.